# When do I use N for the variance of x-bar instead of n-1

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

if the $X_i$'s are all normally distributed

always

if the $X_i$'s are independent of each other

if the $X_i$'s are identical distributed

Comment: Do you have a favorite choice, and (if so) why is that your choice?

Comment: When do you use $n-1$ rather than $n$ in these variance formulas?  Use $n-1$ when you are wanting to describe a larger population that your sample was taken from and there is some uncertainty about whether or not the sample is by itself an accurate description of the larger population as a whole.  Use $n$ when your sample *is* the population itself and there is no uncertainty about whether it could/should be used to describe itself.

Comment: @BruceET my favorite answer is always because all other answer choices seem to be true. However, I know that n-1 is used in some cases so I am not sure.

Comment: If you have a sample $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ from a population, then the sample variance $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$ is a good estimate of the population variance $\sigma^2.$ But I don't see how that is related to your question.// In your question, you'd need for $X_1,X_2,X-3$ to be mutually independent. For example, if they were all the _same,_ then $A = \frac 13(X_1+X_2+X_3) = X_1,$ which has variance $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Just showed you not "always" because independence is important condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simulation below (using R), we have $X_1 = \sqrt{12}\,U,$ where $U\sim\mathsf{Unif}(0,1);$ $X_2 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1);$ $X_3\sim\mathsf{Exp}(1),$ the exponential distribution with rate $1.$ That is, the $X_i$ are independent and $Var(X_1) = Var(X_2) = Var(X_3) = \sigma^2 = 1.$ The simulation illustrates that
$$Var(\bar X) = Var\left[\frac 13(X_1+X_2+X_3)\right] = \frac 19 Var[X_1+X_2+X_3]\\ = \frac 19 [\sigma^2+\sigma^2+\sigma^2] =\frac{\sigma^2}{3} = \frac 13,$$
where independence is used to get from the first line above to the second.
[Note that $Var(X+Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y),$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.]

The $X_i$ are not all normally distributed, are not identically distributed, and are independent. Also, the equation in your Question is true for my random variables.
So what do you think?

```
set.seed(2020)
m = 10^6
x1 = runif(m)*sqrt(12)
x2 = rnorm(m)
x3 = rexp(m)
a = (x1 + x2 + x3)/3  # sample mean
var(a)
[1] 0.3328322         # aprx Var(A) = 1/3
```